# jquery click href to open dropdown chrome mobile android

Tags: jquery, focus

on a mobile when you click the link "bring it up" this demo: http://bit.ly/10E3ScR this will bring up a dropdown menu in safari mobile (IOS) and chrome mobile (IOS) but nothing in chrome mobile (android)!

i just do jQuery('#myselect').select().focus();

Any clue on how i can achieve this little trick in both browser safari & chrome mobile IOS and android?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/byJ4X/

```
jQuery('.mylink').click(function() {
    jQuery('#myselect').select().focus();
});

.myspan{
position: absolute;
top: -9000px;
left: 10px;
}

<span class="myspan">
<select id="myselect" class="" size="5">        
    <option name="option1" value="" class="">option1</option>       
    <option name="option2" value="" class="">option2</option>       
    <option name="option3" value="" class="">option3</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Comment: Not very familiar with mobile dev, are you just trying to show the select if the link is clicked? Why hide the span off screen, just .hide() it and .show() it when your link is clicked? May be there is something special about mobile dev that makes this trickier?

Comment: it is just a requirement. the css on the select is just like that